# Open several windows of the same file in Textmate

Tags: textmate

do you know how can one in Textmate open several windows for the same file?

So I can at the same time look and compare different parts of the same file.

Thanks

Comment: not a real programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one way of doing it is to abuse TextMate Projects with the following script:

```
# we want to force TextMate to open up another window with the document
# if we leave out /dev/null here textmate will simply (re)activate the
# current document. So, while we get a project file with two items
# (the current document - which we wanted a new view of) and an
# empty file named "null", it's the easiest solution I know of
# WD-rpw 03-22-07

tof=` echo $TM_FILEPATH | sed 's/\.[^.]*$/*/' `
mate $tof /dev/null
```

Save this in a new Command in a bundle and you should be ready to go.